# Magento 2 redirects url to https but not admin panel

Tags: magento2, redirect, apache, admin-url

I know this question is more about apache config, but it involves Magento too. Currently i have configured my Magento with 2 different URLs,

for port 443 or 
https I have an url like this:
https://subdomain.domain.org/

for http i have:
http://subdomain.domain.org/folder

I want to redirect whenever a user types subdomain.domain.org to https://subdomain.domain.org, but if i do this my admin panel redirects there too, i have tried RewriteCond but no one of them worked, my admin panel url is:
http://subdomain.domain.org/folder/admin , this link should not be redirected.

Can someone help me to figure out how to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check with below posibilities :

> check with your .htaccess ( url rewrite )
>
> check your admin base url.

i.e htaccess :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  #Include this line if you are using Godaddy hosting
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)subfolder
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subfolder/$1 [L]
```

another option :

goto database `core_cofig` table

path - `admin/url/use_custom` set value `0`

path - `admin/url/use_custom_path` set value `0`

**I hope its very helpful to you**

Comment: Hello, I don't know what i'm doing wrong but this does not work, I put the rule at the end of mod_rewrite.

Comment: please check my answer, i updated, one more possibility.., than please flush cache.

Comment: its working for my side.

Comment: Hello, at the end I used this rule and it worked: RedirectMatch permanent "^(/(?!folder/?).*)" https://subdomain.domain.org/$1 ,I really appreciate your help.